# Solving sparse linear equations in matlab

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

I have a sparse matrix A of very high dimension around `30000x30000`. And my equation is something like this:

```
Ax=b.
```

I cannot take the inverse of A.
So how can I solve the value of `x` in matlab.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/f16-5872.html#f16-6492

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [backslash operator](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) with sparse matrices:

```
x = A\b;
```